# How to specify multiple restrict frame ranges for the F-curve Noise modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers, fcurves

It's a simple problem but one I can't seem to get my head round. I'm using a noise modifier which seems to perfectly mimic a realistic rotation of some equipment I'm deploying. My problem is I need to restrict this twice.

1 start noise at 3000 and end at 3400

2 start again at 4400 and terminate at 5000

I thought about key framing the strength but I can't add any keyframes to the noise panel

Basically I want the F-curve to look like it would do if the lime green line was added

[image]

Thanks for any help
Sean

Comment: OBVIOUSLY!!!!!! Ahh thank you so much for the simple solution. :)

Comment: I edited the title to make it define what exactly is desired from the modifier. Unfortunately I couldn't find related questions for this one so not to answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to let the F-Curve modifier affect the animation in several frame ranges is to setup several F-Curve modifiers. So one modifier will be responsible for the 1-st frame range, another one - for the second and so on.

[image: screenshot-f-curve-modifiers]

You can copy / paste modifiers with buttons in the top part of the [Modifiers tab](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html#f-curve-modifiers) in the Properties region of the [Graph Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html). Once modifier was copied change its frame range to make it affect another part of animation.